# packer - fbsetbg causes recursive login - Ubuntu Server 14.04

Tags: server

I have been trying to create an OVF file using `packer`. Everything works fine until I was trying to set a background image. My JSON file has included `gui.sh` which has:

```
apt-get install fluxbux xinit virtual-box-guest-x11
fbsetbg -f ~/.background.png
service slim start
```

Now if I exclude the `fbsetbg` line, I can log into the OVF machine alright, but the background image is not what I want. As soon as I include the `fbsetbg` command line, I run into login loop. I have tried several attempts but nothing really works.

Any suggestions, please?

Many thanks.